# Assign random number of items from a list to a Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a pandas Dataframe that has two columns and 1000 rows.

The first column I'd like to have a random integer between 100 and 500.

In the second column I'd like to have a random subset of a list, (random number of items and items themselves)

The list from which I'm trying to pull is this one:

```
fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'melon', 'kiwi', 'grape', 'mango', 'peach', 'pear']
```

And here are some examples of what I'm trying to have the Dataframe look like:

```
Column 1        Column 2
  304            ['melon', 'kiwi', 'grape', 'apple']
  176            ['grape', 'banana']
  456            ['strawberry', 'orange', 'melon', 'kiwi']
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For column 1, generate a random array of numbers between 100 and 500 with `numpy`.  For column 2, iteratively choose random subsets of `fruits`.  See the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'melon', 'kiwi', 'grape', 'mango', 'peach', 'pear']

col1 = np.random.randint(100, 500, 1000)

col2 = []
for i in range(1000):
    n = np.random.randint(1, len(fruits) + 1)
    col2.append(np.random.choice(fruits, size=n))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1' : col1,
                   'Column 2' : col2})
```

Example output `df`:

```
  Column 1                                           Column 2
0       163  [peach, strawberry, banana, apple, grape, bana...
1       102  [banana, kiwi, peach, mango, pear, peach, stra...
2       480                             [apple, orange, peach]
3       231                                       [pear, kiwi]
4       202                             [banana, peach, grape]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, if I wanted to make the list unique would the best solution be to apply a lambda function to the list to convert it to a tuple?

Comment: @adrian if you wrap the input to `append` with `tuple()`, you can have tuples instead of lists in your `df`.  **But that will not prevent repeated collections in column 2**!  You would instead need to check if each list (or tuple) is in `col2` before appending  (and take a new sample if not)

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import pandas as pd

fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'melon', 'kiwi', 'grape', 'mango', 'peach', 'pear']

column_1 = [random.randint(300,500) for i in range(1000)]
df = pd.DataFrame(column_1, columns=['column_1'])

df['column_2'] = [[fruits[random.randint(1, len(fruits)-1)] for i in range(random.randint(1, len(fruits)-1))] for x in range(1000)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, if I wanted to make the list unique would the best solution be to apply a lambda function to the list to convert it to a tuple?

Comment: Why would changing the underlying data structure to a tuple create a unique list?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, they both worked and the way to eliminate duplicates was to convert to a set with a lambda function once the random list had been generated.